# How can I create Min stl priority_queue of node structure type

Tags: c++, c, vector, stl, priority-queue

```
struct node
{
node *right;
node *left;
int data;   
};
```

This is my struct node.
Now I am using stl priority queue in order to extract min i.e the minimum from the priority queue like this

```
    std::priority_queue<node*, std::vector<node*>, std::greater<node*> > mypq;
```

But I am not getting the minimum and googled and I found that (greater), It is used for integers and I got another answer and I implemented like this

```
 struct compare  
 {  
 bool operator()(const node*& l, const node*& r)  
  {  
   return l > r;  
   }  
 };
```

And I used like this

```
  std::priority_queue<node*, std::vector<node*>,compare > mypq;
```

But it is showing errors I am frustrated, Any body help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison function should take two arguments that are the type of the elements in the priority queue. The types of your elements are `node*`, so your function should be defined as `bool operator()(node* l, node* r)`. Now, you can write the comparison function taking this into account:

```
struct compare  
{  
  bool operator()(node* l, node* r)  
  {  
    return l->data > r->data;  
  }  
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct compare  
 {  
 bool operator()(const node*& l, const node*& r)  
  {  
   return l->data > r->data;  
   }  
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to compare using the `data` fields of the struct, this type of functor should work:

```
struct compare  
{  
  bool operator()(const node* l, const node* r)  const
  {  
    return l->data > r->data;  
  }  
};
```

where the `bool operator()` is `const` because calling it should not change its state. It is not required by the C++ standard that it be a const method, but some implementations may require it, resulting in compilation errors.